# Using nested ListView or something else?

Tags: android, layout

I have an layout like this:

[image]

I have almost 10 category to display, and each category have 10 books to display.

So it seems that I have to use the `ListView` for category with nested `ListView` for each book.

But I wonder if this will cause the measure problem?  The inner book listivew does not need the scroll feature while the outer listview needs.

I have thought use the `LinearLayout` instead of `ListView` at all by adding each book and category dynamically , however I am not sure about  the performance since the `ListView` can reuse some view, while `LinearLayout` cannot(or hard to).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: ExpandableListView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You should not have problems, your inner `ListView` will not have limited height.

Consider using a `ExpandableListView`, the header will be the category and the childs the books. If you use this remember to override the method `isChildSelectable` to keep all the items expanded and remove the group indicator with `setGroupIndicator(null)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, however I am not sure if the `ExpandableListView` is the right way. Since I have a whole background of for a category and the children, once I test the `ExpandableListView` I found that I can not set the background for the  category and the children together like this:http://i.imgur.com/nabAbcr.png I can just set the bg for the category.